# RxJava 2: Stats about messages dropped because of BackPressure?

Tags: observable, usage-statistics, rx-java2, backpressure

I am using RxJava 2 Flowable with DROP BackPressure strategy.
Is there any way to collect information / stats about how many messages are actually dropped because of the BackPressure?

### Solution

`Flowable#onBackpressureDrop(consumer -> {});`
http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Flowable.html#onBackpressureDrop(io.reactivex.functions.Consumer)

Comment: There is an overload that takes an onDrop handler you can use for counting.

Comment: Indeed, thanks @akarnokd !
http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Flowable.html#onBackpressureDrop(io.reactivex.functions.Consumer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an overload that takes an onDrop handler you can use for counting.

Generally, it is advised to check an operator's overloads for additional features.

Comment: Thanks. There's also a method on the Flowable: http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Flowable.html#onBackpressureDrop(io.reactivex.functions.Consumer)